# How do I set scroll top of a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a problem with set scroll bar top position. Actually what I need is; I am using a JQuery Keyboard plugin where for all the elements I need to display the virtual keyboard at the center bottom of the page and its done.

But the problem I am having is when I have a input field near to the bottom of the page where that page does not display the scroll bar (It means there is no need of overflow because all the elements I have is visible in my page). Since I am displaying the virtual keyboard at the bottom of the page and when the focused element also is at the bottom of the page I need to initiate the scroll bar and page should go up by scroll down automatically so active input field element is visible to me.

I tried to set the scroll bar by using this

```
$(document).scrollTop(_scroll_top + (_el_top + _el_height) - _keyboard_top);
```

Where _scroll_top is my current scroll top position, _el_top is focused elements top position, _el_height is my focused elements height and _keyboard_top is the top position of the keyboard.

Now the problem is when I have a more height page (It means scroll bar size is small i.e. scroll bar size may be around 60% of the screen.Height) scrollTop is correctly working and I can see the active input element even though keyboard is visible. But when I have small height of a page (Example: scroll bar size is around 90% or it may be same size of screen.Height) scrollTop is is not working correctly so the active input element is not visible and it is behind to virtual keyboard.

How can I set the scroll top correctly so I will be able to see the active input element then at the bottom of that element I can see virtual keyboard.

Please see the attached image. That is where actually active input element should be displayed.

First Image is  **Before Enable the keyboard: Just see the element's position, sroll top** 
Second Image is  **After Enable the keyboard: Just see the element's position, sroll top** 
[image: Before Enable the keyboard: Just see the element's position, sroll top]

[image: After enable the keyboard: Just see the element's position, scroll top]

This is what I need when my scroll bar size is big (Around 90% of the screen.Height)

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I am extremely sorry if I confuse by the way I expressed my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.
I have found the solution for my question.
At the bottom of the page I have created a dummy div element.

```
<div id="scroll_dummy"></div>
```

Initially this div will be having zero height. I applied the height of the keyboard to this div. As a result your page size will be increased so it can easily move the scroll top. At the time of close again revert back this style.

Then at the place of I am applying scrollTop I have done this.

```
$("#scroll_dummy").css("height", _keyboard_height);
$(document).scrollTop(_scroll_top + (_el_top + _el_height) - _keyboard_top);
```

Where

- _scroll_top : scroll top position
- _el_top : active element top position
- _el_height : active element height
- _keyboard_top : keyboard element top position
- _keyboard_height : keyboard element height position

Done with this... :)

Answer (score 0):

use `jQuery('html,body').scrollTop('other things here')`;

Comment: I can use but when the ScrollBar size is small it does not have enough place to move the srollTop to the size I need.. :(